# Failed to create mutliple instances of mongodb in ubuntu

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I'm trying to  create multiple instances of mongodb in ubuntu, but I'm getting error.

`mongod --port 27018 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb2`

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.427+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.427+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.428+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.429+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.429+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.429+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.429+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.429+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":12277,"port":27018,"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb2","architecture":"64-bit","host":"jackson-PC"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.429+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.5","gitVersion":"c9a99c120371d4d4c52cbb15dac34a36ce8d3b1d","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu2204","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.429+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"22.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.429+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"port":27018},"storage":{"dbPath":"/var/lib/mongodb2"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.430+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /var/lib/mongodb2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.430+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.430+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4794602, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.430+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":6371601, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FLE Crud thread pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.430+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.430+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.430+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.430+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.430+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.430+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.430+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.430+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.430+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.431+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.431+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.431+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.431+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.431+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6278511, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the Change Stream Expired Pre-images Remover"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.431+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.431+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.431+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.431+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

I thought it's about permissions because there is

`{"t":{"$date":"2023-03-28T18:34:10.430+05:30"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /var/lib/mongodb2"}}`

so I have given permissions also

`ls -al /var/lib/mongodb2`

```
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  2 mongodb mongodb 4096 Mar 28 15:32 .
drwxr-xr-x 74 root    root    4096 Mar 28 15:32 ..
```

I have given the required permission I believe but still getting this error

Answer (score 0):

When you run multiple instances on one machine, then you must use different

- `net.port`
- `storage.dbPath`
- `processManagement.pidFilePath`

and it would be smart to use also different

- `systemLog.path`

Looks like, you try to use `storage.dbPath` more than once.

I would suggest to use a [configuration file](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/) rather than command line options.

Comment: hey i did created a new config file and wrote db path, port , system log path also and did mongod  --config but when i tried to connect it these errors arise

Comment: Check if no other `mongod` process is running. Did you start as `mongodb` user?

Comment: I have stopped mongodb process also, still same. Is it the right way to create multiple instances?